# Topple Magazine Presents: Cover Letters

Tags: logical-deduction, word

Here is a word game; I hope that you enjoy it.

[image: Word Puzzle]

To clarify a bit on the part of "Every letter belongs to a group of four letters, and this bond must be maintained", here's a picture showing a valid configuration (though it is not a valid solution, since the rows and columns do not yield any words):

[image: Pattern clarification]

One line shaped segment, one square segment and two L-shaped segments are used, of which one is reflected. Though no rotations are present in this example, these are also allowed (e.g. it would be valid to rotate this picture 90 degrees, though this would still not give a valid solution). Also note, that while I've adhered somewhat to the ordering as given in the problem statement, the letters can be arranged in any order, i.e. the first line might just as well be slge.

Comment: any proper nouns like"Reno" ?

Comment: Nope, no proper nouns.

Comment: Does changing the orientation allow reflections as well as rotations?

Comment: I may have used the wrong word there. Any positioning is allowed that keeps the shapes intact while also making it so only legal shapes are on the board. So reflections are okay.

Comment: Can you give example (non valid word) for "Every letter belongs to a group..."

Comment: On the stone tablet there are four grooves where the tiles are located.  All the letters in each section have to be used together in one of the formations shown:  a square, a straight line, or a mostly straight line with a turn at the end.

Comment: @Topple Unless I'm terribly mistaken (in which case, please add an example yourself), I've added a valid configuration (no solution) as an example to help clarify the requirements.

Comment: @Lolgast That is exactly a good example of how it could look.  Thank you for the clarification.  Four groups of letters across four shapes that fill the board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have got the right answer

> ```
> darn
> oboe
> glow
> sets
> ```

The words are

> darn, oboe, glow, sets, dogs, able, root, and news
>  all use the square pattern!

The patterns

> da | rn 
>      ob | oe
>      --------
>      g l | ow
>      se | ts

Comment: @Topple Great puzzle, take me hours to solve, I have upvote your puzzle since my first answer.

Comment: I am glad you liked the puzzle, and kudos on solving it.  That is some real commitment.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get :

> w e s t
>      e s o l
>      r o d o
>      g n a b
>
>  Maybe not the intended words, because I still can't understand the rules
>  for words at the rows WEST, LOSE, ODOR, BANG
>  and for words at the coloumn GREW, NOSE, SODA and BOLT

Comment: This is actually pretty impressive.  It looks like you lost your letter bonds, though.  Like EONR* has to be a line, a square, or the hooked shape but it looks like it fell apart.  Same for the other groups.  As for the columns and rows, they will yield a word when reading the grid top to bottom and left to right.

*Groups have static shapes but not static order within shapes.